# Can I validate dynamically created forms using jquery validation engine?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validation-engine

The problem is that the form which I'm trying to validate is located on a page which is loaded via AJAX. I've tried to call validationengine after the page is loaded, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to use this plugin to validate such forms?

Comment: Can you show the js code that validates the form and the form html code

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The validation engine would not work with forms loaded via AJAX. What worked for me was first to detach the validation engine from all the forms then reattach:

```
$('form').validationEngine('detach');
$('#yourform').validationEngine();
```

Specifically, I was loading the form via AJAX in a modal popup. Here is the full code which also includes a close function to destroy the popup:

```
$('<div>Loading...</div>')
.load(url, function() {
    $('form').validationEngine('detach');
    $('#yourform').validationEngine(); 
})
.dialog({
    modal: true,
    height:400,
    width:400,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Stefan P. that some code example would help. However, from the [documentation](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#instantiation) is seems that you can simply add the following to your AJAX success handler:

```
$("#id-of-dynamically-loaded-form").validationEngine();
```

For example, if you use `$.load` for doing the AJAX request, this could look like this:

```
$('#somewhere').load('someurl', function() {
  // Instantiate validation-engine
  $("#id-of-dynamically-loaded-form").validationEngine();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue i just got my whole form through get request and jquery validation engine was not working at all. I searched a lot and finally at the end i found that if we are validating the form on click of button then we should first deatach and then attach the validation engine because the form gets multiple events attached with it therefore deatach is recommended. 
For Example i got the form with `id="Table1`" and on `save button` click i would do this

```
$("#Table1").validationEngine('detach');
$("#Table1").validationEngine('attach');
$("#Table1").validationEngine('validate');
```

after the execution of `$("#Table1").validationEngine('validate');` this line it will give you a boolean value `true or false` on its return value you can `save or show errors` on the form